# A *a = new A(); Does this create a pointer or an object?

Tags: c++

```
A *a = new A();
```

Does this create a pointer or an object?

I am a c++ beginner, so I want to understand this difference.

Comment: If it only created a pointer, what would that pointer point to exactly?

Comment: When you purchase a new home, have you obtained a new street address, or a new house?

Comment: A pointer is also an object itself.

Comment: `A *a` is the pointer.  It can hold an address.  `new A()` returns the address of a newly-created object.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Both: you created a new instance of `A` (an object), and created a pointer to it called `a`.

You could separate it into two statements:

```
A *a;        // Declare `a` of type: pointer to `A`

a = new A(); // create a new instance of `A` and
             // assign the resulting pointer to `a`
```

Answer (score 15):

This creates an object of type `A` on the heap, and stores a pointer to it in `a` (that is stored on the stack).

P.S. Don't forget to call `delete a` when you're done with it, so that `A` can be destroyed and its memory given back to the heap. Better still, turn `a` into a smart pointer.

Comment: I hope you do not mind the tiny edit to clarify where `a` is stored.

Comment: what if constructor of A class isn`t exception save - then exception can be thrown and no instance will be created, also after you call delete in such situation you will get a run-time error.

Comment: More like don't forget to use a smart pointer instead of worrying about safely deleting it.

Comment: @spin_eight - initialize the pointer to 0; then if the constructor for `A` throws an exception, `delete a` is still ok. No need for smart pointers or for checking anything.

Comment: @ Pete Becker  actually I mean that this answer could contain more detailed info, that it doesn`t cover all possible variants, and to cover them all a lot of info should be given. I think that it will be good to provide to the topic starter refernces on books/sites for begginers when trying to cover such theam in a rather short answer. Also to add - operator new can be overloaded, so in that case you can`t garantee that an instance of the class will be created

Comment: @spin_eight: If you think an answer would benefit from a lot more detail (I don't), I think the most constructive approach is to write your own.

Answer (score 11):

It creates both.
It creates object of type `A*` on the stack and object of type `A` on the heap.

Equivalent to

```
A *a;
a = new A();
```

Answer (score 4):

It will create both object as well as pointer.

Firstlly new A() is called and if you have default constructor then it call that constructor and initialize that object with default values otherwise it will initialize with defaul values.Because we are using new keywork then it will allocate the memory for object A on heap.`New` keyword is used to allocate memory dynamically on heap.`NEW` returns the starting address of the object.

After that A type pointer which will have the address of object A() returned by the `new` operator.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, it creates both. But the object A is created on free store and now you have to remember to manually `delete` it. Remember, that any function in C++ can throw an exception unless it is declared as `noexcept`. So now not only you have to remember to `delete` when no exception is thrown, you will now also need to imagine all the paths the code could take and write appropriate `try-catch` blocks to manually `delete` your object.

What you are doing is called naked new and it is an easy way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Thankfully, C++11 has a solution to this problem: smart pointers. Consider the semantics of your pointer, will it be owned by a one entity or shared between several ones? In the former case, you'll need `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<A> a(new A{});
```

Now you don't need to call `delete`, memory management has been taken care of for you. In the latter case, you'll need `std::shared_ptr`

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<A> a(new A{});
```

But the definition on C++ sequence points may not guarantee that this way of creating smart pointers will always be safe, without getting into details:

```
std::shared_ptr<A>(new A{new B, new C});
```

May produce memory leaks, to avoid this, use `std::make_shared`

```
#include <memory>

auto a = std::make_shared<A>(); // a now holds a shared_ptr to A
```

Unfortunately, when finalizing C++11, committee forgot about `std::make_unique`. This should be fixed in C++14:

```
#include <memory>

auto a = std::make_unique<A>(); // a now holds a unique_ptr to A
```

Answer (score 1):

It creates both.

First you create an object of type A and then store a pointer to it

For more information on pointers please have a look at [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Answer (score 0):

an object and pointer. The object has to have a pointer for you to reference, however, you can have one one object pointed by several pointer.